# Find a value in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, flask-sqlalchemy

```
[
{
  'v_id': UUID('046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91'), 's_id': UUID('c725e295-737b-495c-8428-704ec3257a7c'), 
  'service_ids': 
  [UUID('8fe1e5bf-9150-442d-ad6d-7d16f942ecef')]
  
}, 
{
  'v_id': UUID('046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91'), 's_id': UUID('8fb1f888-176b-4b51-8eee-2b15bf4a5d19'), 
  'service_ids': 
  [UUID('9fe1e5bf-9150-442d-ad6d-7d16f942ecef'), 
  UUID('8fe1e5bf-9150-442d-ad6d-7d16f942ecef')]
  
}
]
```

this is my dictionary which contains ids of my services .

and this is JSON output

```
[
  {
    "s_id": "c725e295-737b-495c-8428-704ec3257a7c",
    "service_ids": [
      "8fe1e5bf-9150-442d-ad6d-7d16f942ecef"
    ],
    "v_id": "046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91"
  },
  {
    "s_id": "8fb1f888-176b-4b51-8eee-2b15bf4a5d19",
    "service_ids": [
      "9fe1e5bf-9150-442d-ad6d-7d16f942ecef",
      "8fe1e5bf-9150-442d-ad6d-7d16f942ecef"
    ],
    "v_id": "046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91"
  }
]
```

I want to find if given service id is available in this list(inside service_ids) or not. How to do this ?

Here what I tried. But its not working

```
attached_list = ServiceAttachment.query.all()
    attached_dict_list = []   //This is the dictionary I mentioned above.
    for services in attached_list:
        attached_dict_list.append(services)
    print(attached_dict_list)
    if service_id in attached_dict_list:
        print(service_id )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us you code!

Comment: As a human being, how would go about this task?  It's the same process.

Comment: I edit the question with the code I tried

Comment: @Tim CTRL+F? 

Comment: `any(service_id in d['service_ids'] for d in attached_list)`

Comment: `attached_dict_list` is a `list`, not `dict`. And having  `dict` and `list` as part of the name does not make much sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer

```
attached_list = ServiceAttachment.query.all()
    attached_dict_list = []   //This is the dictionary I mentioned above.
    for services in attached_list:
        attached_dict_list.append(services)

 for d in attached_dict_list:
        if service_id in str(d['service_ids']):
            print(service_id )
        else:
            print('Not found')
```

Comment: No. You're turning an entire list into a string, and then do substring matching. That may happen to work, but only by coincidence. You want `d['service_ids']` to remain a list, but turn every individual element in it into a string. For that you could `map` it: `service_id in map(str, d['service_ids'])`. Or you turn the test value into a UUID: `UUID(service_id) in d['service_ids']`.

Comment: Thankyou @deceze . ```service_id in map(str, d['service_ids']) ``` this works. For turn test value into uuid , need to define uuid . ```NameError: name 'UUID' is not defined ```

Comment: Yeah, you need to `from uuid import UUID`.

Answer (score 1):

```
attached_list = ServiceAttachment.query.all()
attached_dict_list = []

for service in attached_list:
    for available in attached_dict_list:
        if service in available['service_ids']:
            print(service, available['s_id'])
            break
```